# Initializing variables from a restored model in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, restore

Suppose that I train and save the following simple network (Lets call it network A):

```
Input --> Conv1 --> Conv2 --> Conv3 --> Output
```

Now, I would like to restore network A, design a new network B and use parameters of network A to initialize the first 3 layers of network B:

```
Input --> Conv1 --> Conv2 --> Conv3 --> Conv4 --> Conv5 --> Output
```

How can I do this in TensorFlow?

Answer (score 0):

You can just create network A + B, and remember the Conv3 layer. You can then compute a loss on the output of Conv3, then train for a while. Once you are satisfied, just switch to training on a loss on Conv5.